# Как проверить правильность перевода чисел между системами счисления?

Tags: математика, информатика, системы-счисления

В моем учебнике есть вот такой текст задачи:

> Число X в шеснадцатиричной системе счисления оканчивается на 9(16), а в восьмеричной системе счисления трехзначное и начинается на 23(8). Укажите это число в десятичной системе счисления.

Мои рассуждения такие:

1. Находим минимальное из возможных чисел 23x(8) в шестнадцатеричной системе: 230(8) = 152(10) = 98(16).
2. Находим максимальное из возможных чисел 23x (8) в шестнадцатеричной системе: 237(8) = 159(10) = 9F(16).
3. Имеется диапазон возможных чисел в шестнадцатеричной системе: 98(16) .. 9F(16). По условию знаем, что число в шестнадцатеричной системе оканчивается на 9(16) - значит, это 99(16).
4. 99(16) = 153(10).

Ответ в учебнике: 147(10).

Подскажите, как мне проверить, какой из ответов правильный - это ошибка в моих рассуждениях или в учебнике ответ неправильный?

Comment: А вы пробовали перевести 147 в (8) и (16) системы счисления? Оно не удовлетворяет обоим условиям задачи.

Comment: Учитывая, что 147(10) не оканчивается на 9(16) - скорее всего в учебнике.

Comment: Но! Число 147 удовлетворяет условию задачи, если его немного "инвертировать" - оно оканчивается на 23(8) и начинается с 9(16). В учебнике явно ошибка - вопрос где.

Comment: @Kromster, да, упустил этот момент, спасибо.

Comment: @Zufir, интересная ситуация, скорее всего, ошибка в условии.  И это не первая ошибка в учебнике (ЕГЭ-2017 Д.М. Ушакова). Некачественный учебник?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы узнать, *"это ошибка в моих рассуждениях или в учебнике ответ неправильный"*, вам нужно проверить ваш ответ и ответ из учебника:

1. Возьмите два варианта ответа - 153(10) и 147(10)
2. Переведите их в (8) систему счисления
3. Проверьте совпадает ли результат с условием задачи
4. Переведите варианты ответа в (16) систему счисления
5. Проверьте совпадает ли результат с условием задачи

*для ускорения, вы можете воспользоваться стандартным Калькулятором в Windows, переведя его в режим "Программиста" (Меню -> Вид -> Программист), там перевод между системами счисления делается одним кликом в радио-группе.

Answer (score 0):

С позиций реальных программистов тут даже думать не надо.

Задача очевидно и мгновенно решается "методом грубой силы"
(поскольку сказано, что число, записанное в восьмеричной системе *трехзначное* и начинается с 23, то  достаточно перебрать всего-то 8 вариантов)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int oct = 0230, i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if ((oct + i) % 16 == 9) 
      break;

  if (i < 8)
    printf("result x = oct: %o  hex: %x  dec: %d\n",
       oct + i, oct + i, oct + i);
  else
    puts("No such number");

  return 0;
}
```

(и видим, что ответ не как в учебнике)

```
avp@wubu:hashcode$ ./a.out 
result x = oct: 231  hex: 99  dec: 153
avp@wubu:hashcode$
```

---

Если же зануды потребуют рассуждений, то решить задачку можно так.

1) Переведем 230 восьмиричное в привычное для ручного деления десятичное
2 * 64 + 3 * 8 = 152

2) Найдем остаток от деления на 16, чтобы узнать насколько далеко мы находимся от искомого шестнадцатеричного, оканчивающегося на 9
152 / 16 = 9; 9 * 16 = 144; 152 - 144 = 8 (это остаток)

3) Видим, что остаток для десятичного 152 = 8, очевидно, что желаемую 9-ку даст следующее число -- **153**.